# Making specific frequency (ranges) louder

Tags: python, audio, frequency

I want to make certain frequencies in a sequence of audio data louder. I have already analyzed the data using FFT and have gotten a value for each audio frequency in the data. I just have no idea how I can use the frequencies to manipulate the sound data itself.

From what I understand so far, data is encoded in such a way that the difference between every two consecutive   readings determines the audio amplitude at that time instant. So making the audio louder at that time instant would involve making the difference between the two consecutive readings greater. But how do I know which time instants are involved with which frequency? I don't know *when* the frequency starts appearing.

(I am using Python, specifically PyAudio for getting the audio data and Num/SciPy for the FFT, though this probably shouldn't be relevant.)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a graphic equalizer.  Some quick Googling turned up [rbeq](http://code.google.com/p/rbeq/), which seems to be a plugin for Rhythmbox written in Python.  I haven't looked through the code to see if the actual EQ part is written in Python or is just controlling something in the host, but I recommend looking through their source.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I looked up the source of rbeq and found out that it uses the 10-band equalizer plugin for GST, written in C++. I'll try to look up the source for that, though it seems like I'm just digging deeper and deeper.